# Post it back send to my controller method the file ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC webpage with `DropDownList`, this list is full of items and after click on the button i have notice that my controller method (Index) received an number as string so i have checked in my database and this number is my object ID.
is it possible to get another property of this item instead of this ID ?

Here is my view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files, "Id", "protocol_site"), "Select webmail site", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" })
    <button type="submit">Select</button>
</div>
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string File)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the second parameter of your `SelectList` to the property name of the object you want to send to your controller.

```
 new SelectList(ViewBag.Files, "PropertyName", "protocol_site")
```

Comment: Thanks !, BTW after get this and make database query how can i return list of my object and show thowse files in list over the webpage ?

Comment: you mean the filenames?

Comment: I mean all my object with all the properties inside something like maybe ListView and columns, is it possible?